# Can fromfile omit fields?

Tags: numpy, fromfile

I am reading data from a given binary format, however I am only interested in a subset of the fields.

For example:

```
MY_DTYPE = np.dtype({'names': ('A', 'B', 'C'), 'formats': ('<f8', '<u2', 'u1')})

data = np.fromfile(infile, count=-1, dtype=MY_DTYPE)
```

Assume I don't really need `data['C']`, is it possible to specify what fields I want to keep in the first place?

Comment: Remove it after loading.

Answer (score 1):

Simulate the load:

```
In [117]: MY_DTYPE = np.dtype({'names': ('A', 'B', 'C'), 'formats': ('<f8', '<u2', 'u1')})                   
In [118]: data = np.zeros(3, MY_DTYPE)                                                                       
In [119]: data                                                                                               
Out[119]: 
array([(0., 0, 0), (0., 0, 0), (0., 0, 0)],
      dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<u2'), ('C', 'u1')])
In [120]: data['C']                                                                                          
Out[120]: array([0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

In the latest numpy version, multifield indexing creates a `view`:

```
In [121]: data[['A','B']]                                                                                    
Out[121]: 
array([(0., 0), (0., 0), (0., 0)],
      dtype={'names':['A','B'], 'formats':['<f8','<u2'], 'offsets':[0,8], 'itemsize':11})
```

It provides a `repack_fields` functions to make a proper `copy`:

```
In [122]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf                                                                
In [123]: rf.repack_fields(data[['A','B']])                                                                  
Out[123]: array([(0., 0), (0., 0), (0., 0)], dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<u2')])
```

See the docs of `repack` for more information, or look at recent release notes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does that mean that both `data` and the new copy are in memory at the same time?

Comment: `Out[121]` is a `view`, but `Out[123]` is a `copy`, a new array.  It does not replace `data`.

Comment: I'm running into a memory problem I want to solve, I could load more if certain fields are never stored in the first place.